# Trying to replace a modem but encountering errors

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, kernel

I've been having connectivity problems on my i9505 LTE on every ROM I've tried since August. Searching around reveals that the outdated modem is the source of the troubles, and that by using the latest firmware the problem should cease.

I've downloaded my latest firmware (XXUGNF6) and tried flashing with Mobile Odin Pro. I get the error "Memory lock in place - TriangleAway may fix this. Skipping flash."

To use TriangleAway I have to be on a stock kernel and recovery (I think). However if Mobile Odin can't flash a new modem, it's going to struggle flashing a kernel and recovery right?

First question: by stock, does it mean stock Android (i.e. AOSP?) or stock as in original for my phone (Galaxy S4 i9505 LTE (H3G)?)

Here's the plan of action, do you agree that this *should* work?

1. Full wipe and install a stock ROM. This should contain a stock kernel.
2. TriangleAway reset.
3. Mobile Odin the latest firmware modem.
4. Reflash my current ROM

NB: I can't use Odin on PC as I'm at work with no admin rights. Failing this I could try at home. Does anyone think just flashing the modem straight away via PC would work?

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved myself. Solution:

1) Flash stock ROM through Odin on PC. Lost all SD content but retained external SD content.

2) This resulted in a weird encryption thing, so I flashed PhilZ recovery and then flashed a third-party ROM from my external SD.

3) Bootable, and modem is updated because I flashed the newer stock.